# undefined method insert_record for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Model A which has many objects of Model B using a `:has_many` association. When I create a new object of model A, set its attributes, build associated objects and inspect the non-persisted objects, it works fine. However, as soon as I try to persist the objects using `save` or `save!`, I am getting the following back-trace.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `insert_record' for #<Array:0x000000052541f8>
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:154:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:306:in `block in save_collection_association'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:431:in `block in method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `block in method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:431:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:297:in `save_collection_association'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:163:in `block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_create_callbacks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `create'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:246:in `create_or_update'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create_or_update'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'
... 2 levels...
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in save'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `block in save'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
    from (irb):104
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/amitav/WMS/trunk/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /home/amitav/WMS/trunk/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I am using ruby 2.0.0p195 with rails 3.0.5.

Comment: See my answer. It's 2 hours ago but you did not mention if my answer was right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an compatibilityproblem. Update your Rails to a newer version `v3.2 >=`

Comment: As verified at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11026 the bug is not present in currently supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you don't want to upgrade your Rails 3.0.x project, make sure you run in on the ruby version where you developed it, e.g. 1.9.2 or 1.9.3.
With rvm or rbenv that should't be a problem.